# Assigning keyword return value to variable not working in Robot Framework

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I have the following Robot Framework keyword, designed to get the full path of the "Downloads" directory in Windows:

```
Get Download Directory
    ${user_home_dir}=   Get Environment Variable    UserProfile
    ${download_dir}=    ${user_home_dir}\\Downloads
    [return]    ${download_dir}
```

This is being assigned to a variable:

```
${download_dir}                         Get Download Directory
```

However, it seems that the proper value is not being assigned. The following:

```
Log To Console                      "Download directory: " ${download_dir}
```

logs `"Download directory: " Get Download Directory` to the console. Why is this the case?

Note that the assignment to the `${download_dir}` variable is being made in the `*** Variables ***` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*** Test Cases ***
One Return Value
    ${ret} =    Return One Value    argument

Multiple Values
    ${a}    ${b}    ${c} =    Return Three Values
    @{list} =    Return Three Values
    ${scalar}    @{rest} =    Return Three Values

*** Keywords ***
Return One Value
    [Arguments]    ${arg}
    ${value}=    Set Variable    1
    [Return]    ${value}

Return Three Values
    [Return]    foo    bar    zap
```

you have to use set variable keyword to set a variable,

```
            ${download_dir}=    Set Variable    ${user_home_dir}\\Downloads
            [return]    ${download_dir}
```